# pointer to pointer for struct

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I have the following code

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int age;
} data;

int storage (data **str) {
    *str = malloc(4 * sizeof(**str));
    (*str)[0].age = 12;
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    data *variable = NULL;
    storage(&variable);
    return 0;
}
```

I took it from a website source. I think I have a misunderstanding about a basic pointer to pointer concept because here in this code, we have a pointer to a struct, `variable`, and we are passing this to `storage` function, which expects pointer to pointer of struct type. After memory was malloced, I don't understand this assignment

```
(*str)[0].age = 12
```

It was assigned as if, `str` was of `(*)[]` type. I dont understand how this assignment works, like `str` is now a pointer to an array of structs?

Comment: Have you looked up what the `&`-operator does?

Comment: gives the address of the variable

Comment: So, you are not passing `variable` to the function `storage()`, you are passing *the address of* `variable`.

Comment: I understand that. And I am assigning memory to the pointer to the structure.

Comment: The line `(*str)[0].age = 12;` is equivalent to `(**str).age = 12;`, is equivalent to `(*str)->age = 12;` is equivalent to `str[0]->age = 12;` is equivalent to `str[0][0].age = 12;`. What's confusing about that?

Comment: `(*str)[0].age = 12; is equivalent to (**str).age = 12;`
This line.. Why is (**str).age equivalent to (*str)[0] ? I know this is pretty simple for you, and I suggest you save your digital breath and not get annoyed.

Comment: I'm not annoyed, I'm amused. Generally, `a[b]` is equivalent to `*(a+b)`. Also, `(*a).m` is equivalent to `a->m`. Also, `a + 0` is equivalent to `a`. So, `a[0]` is equivalent to `*a`. The complication is that postfix-operators have higher precedence than unary-operators, so some of the expressions require parentheses.

Comment: I understand that a[0] is equivalent to *a, but the other way around is not true. I cant write a[0] instead of *a in a code. If I have a int *a, I cannot use it like a[0], but if I have an array defined, I can use a[0] as *a. So, thats what my question was, how is (**str) being treated as (*str)[0]. Do I always treat pointer-to-pointer variable as ( * )[0]

Comment: When I say that `a[b]` is equivalent to `*(a+b)`, I mean **equivalent**. The "direction" in which you exchange one of these expressions with the other *does not matter*. So your belief that `a[b]` can only be used if `a` is an array is false. In fact, by the time `a[b]` is evaluated, `a` is no longer treated as an array, but as a pointer.

Comment: `*str` is a pointer to an array of structs. The array was allocated by `malloc`.

Comment: @EOF s/Generally/Always.  But `a + 0` is only equivalent to `a` when `a` points to an object (or one past the end).

Comment: @M.M For well-defined expressions `a[b]` or `*(a+b)`, yes, always (including `b[a]`).

Comment: And for ill-formed or undefined expressions, both are ill-formed or undefined :)

Comment: @M.M: As for the equivalence of `a + 0` and `a`, the only difference I see is that if `a` is a pointer `a` is an lvalue.

Comment: @EOF if `a` is null pointer then `a + 0` causes undefined behaviour

Comment: @EOF, and @ M.M  thanks for enlightening. My answer was completely erroneous and I apologise for wrong arguments.

Comment: We all learn new things about C all the time. For example, @M.M, C11 draft standard n1570 `6.5 Expressions 6 The effective type of an object for an access to its stored value is the declared type of the object, if any. 87) Allocated objects have no declared type.` Why would you say that there is an *array* allocated by `malloc()`?

Comment: @EOF it's shorter than saying three paragraphs of pedantically-selected wording to get the same point across. We all know what someone means if they say that they "malloc an int" .

Comment: @M.M But saying that "`*str` is a pointer to an array of structs" is actually more confusing than helpful. Saying that `*str` points to the first element of an array of structs would be a lot closer.

Comment: @EOF I agree, however the standard sets a precedent (see 7.1.1/1 definition of *pointer to a string*)

Comment: @M.M: But the standard does not say that a string turns into a pointer, whereas that is what happens to arrays.

Comment: An array that contains a string does turn into a pointer..:)

Comment: My point is that if `*str` is a pointer to an array of struct, `**str` will be of type array of struct, thus according to `6.3.2.1`, `***str` will be of type `struct`, which is clearly wrong. On the other hand, a `string` doesn't turn into a pointer, so this problem doesn't arise. I find your precedent to be unconvincing.

Comment: `*str` has type `data *`. I'm not sure what the relevance is of whatever point you are trying to make, sorry.

Comment: @EOF I have a comment for you in Ander's answer. Can you please take a look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a note about C syntax for dereferencing pointers:

`a[b]` is equivalent to `*(a + b)`, is equivalent to `*(b + a)`, is equivalent to `b[a]`.

Now, in

```
int main() {
    data *variable = NULL;
    storage(&variable);
    return 0;
}
```

`variable` is of type "pointer to `data`", therefore its address `&variable` is of type "pointer to pointer to `data`". This is passed to `int storage(data **str)`, and is the correct type for the argument `str`.

```
int storage (data **str) {
    *str = malloc(4 * sizeof(**str));
    (*str)[0].age = 12;
    return 0;
}
```

Here, `str` is dereferenced, yielding an lvalue of type `data *` designating the same object as `main()`s `variable`. Since it is an lvalue, it can be assigned to.

`malloc()` allocates memory without declared type, large enough (and sufficiently aligned) to contain four contiguous objects of type `data`. It returns a pointer to the beginning of the allocation.

`(*str)[0]` is now an lvalue designating an object of type `data`, and by accessing the memory `malloc()` allocated through this expression, the *effective type* of the memory becomes `data`. `(*str)[0].age = 12;` assigns the value `12` to the `age`-member of this object, leaving the other members of the struct (and the rest of the allocated memory) uninitialized.

Answer (score 2):

It can be illustrated like this

```
main:
 data* variable = NULL;   //variable is a pointer
 storage(&variable)       //the address of the pointer is &variable
```

the `storage(data**)` allows the function to take the address
of the pointer `variable`

this allows `storage` to change what `variable` points to

In `storage`, the following statement changes what `variable` points to by dereferencing (since we did pass the address of `variable`):

```
*str = malloc(4 * sizeof(**str) )
```

The malloc allocates a memory block containing four structs (which each has the size sizeof(struct data) bytes)

A struct is just a convenient way to access a part of memory, the
struct describes the layout of the memory. The statement

```
(*str)[0].age = 12;
```

is the equivalent of

```
data* d = *str; 
d[0].age = 12;
```

or you can write it as a ptr with offset:

```
data* d = *str;
*(d + 0).age = 12;
```

edit: a clarification about malloc

`malloc` returns a block of memory allocated in bytes, the return type of `malloc` is `void*` so per definition it has no type and can be assigned to a pointer of arbitrary type:

```
T* ptr = malloc(n * sizeof(T));
```

After the assignment to ptr, the memory is treated as one or more elements of type T by using the pointer T*

Comment: In your statement, when you say that malloc allocates an array of 4 structs, that is where I get confused. As @EOF pointed in his comments, I understood the part where i can treat `a[b] is equivalent to *(a+b)` equivalent, I figured I could deduce **str expression to an array to first element, but after reading your answer, i am confused still. Malloc is just allocating memory space, how do you figure it is an array of 4 structs? The way I read it, size is just 4*sizeof(struct)

Comment: @Semantics: Well, `malloc()` *doesn't* allocate an array. It allocates memory with no declared type. However, by the rules of C11 `6.5 Expressions, 6 effective type`, once you've *used* the memory for a particular type, it *becomes* that type. Therefore, you can *treat* the pointer returned by `malloc()` as a pointer to the first element of an array.

Comment: @EOF Yes exactly thats what I needed to know. This is the information that I was looking for. Post it as an answer if you can and I will be happy to accept it. or if Anders can include this info as well in his answer

Comment: @Semantics the return type of `malloc` is `void*` so it has no type, it is just a chunk of memory. The pointer type is the one that decides how the memory should be addressed e.g. calculating the offset of bytes when you do `ptr + 1`

Comment: @AndersK. The memory allocated by `malloc()` does not become the type the pointer it is assigned to points to. It is only the act of *storing an object of the type* that causes the *effective type* of the memory to be determined. See C11  draft standard n1570, `6.5 Expressions, 6 effective type`

Comment: yes that is what i said (or was trying to say), it does not become the type of the pointer. i said you access the memory through the pointer. have edited my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think your code is simply identical to:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    int age;
} data;

int main()
{
    data *variable = NULL;
    variable = malloc(4 * sizeof(*variable));
    *(variable + 0).age = 12;
    return 0;
}
```

So `variable` is malloced with a block of memory, which is large enough to hold 4 `data`s(from `variable[0]` to `variable[3]`). That's all.

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code might help illustrate what's happening, the really interesting line is

```
assert(sizeof(**str2) == sizeof(data));
```

Your numbers may vary form mine but first lets create a struct with a rather dull but hard to fake size for testing purposes.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
  uint8_t  age;
  uint8_t  here_as_illustartion_only[1728];
} data;

int main() {
    data    str; 
    data *  str1 = &str;  
    data ** str2 = &str1;  
    printf("sizeof(str)    =%*zu\n", 5, sizeof(str));
    printf("sizeof(str1)   =%*zu\n", 5, sizeof(str1));
    printf("sizeof(str2)   =%*zu\n", 5, sizeof(str2));
    printf("sizeof(*str2)  =%*zu\n", 5, sizeof(*str2));
    printf("sizeof(**str2) =%*zu\n", 5, sizeof(**str2));

    assert(sizeof(**str2) == sizeof(data));
    return 0;
}
```

On my machine this prints the following

```
sizeof(str)    = 1729
sizeof(str1)   =    8
sizeof(str2)   =    8
sizeof(*str2)  =    8
sizeof(**str2) = 1729
```

Note the size of the pointer to pointer ie **sizeof(**)** is the dull number we're looking for.